# Apply styles to text that's not inside of any HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

Is it possible to apply css or javascript to text that is not within any particular tag? Here is an example:

```
<td valign="top">
    <span class="PageText_L71n">Quantity</span> 
    : 
    <input type="text" class="v65-productdetail-cartqty" name="QTY.BF-BLU" size="3" maxlength="8" onkeydown="javascript:QtyEnabledAddToCart();" value="1">
</td>
```

I want to be able to edit the ":" between the span and input tags. This HTML cannot be edited, as it is generated by the eCommerce platform I am using (Volusion).

Here is a photo of what this looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfXbq.png

Comment: quite the contrary because `:` is between `<td valign="top"></td>`

Comment: CSS can only affect content of tags. You'd have to use JavaScript to wrap the content in a tag.  Perhaps [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) would be helpful to you.

Comment: everything is generally going to between a tag `<html>` being the highest tag hierarchy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like, you will have to fine tune the css selectors so that it will be applied to only the desired elements

```
td {
    color: <same as the background>;
}

td * {
    color: black;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CaT6M/)